# calculating circular arrangments

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

we know that the number of possible arrangements of r objects in n places in a circle is (n-1)P(r-1) but in the case of neighboring objects the  number of possible arrangements becomes n(r)! which is greater than the number in the first case 
my question is how it works?
Is not the first case includes the entire second case ?

Comment: When you say "in the case of neighboring objects," do you mean that all $n$ places in the circle are occupied?  If so, the formula should be $(n - 1)! = P(n - 1, n - 1)$.

Comment: All places can not be occupied at the same time because the number of persons less than the number of places but i mean all persons should be behind each other i.e there is no empty place in between

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise specified, in circular arrangements, only the relative order of the objects matters.

> In how many ways can $r$ objects be arranged in a circle when $n$ places are available?

**Method 1:**  We place one of the objects.  That object will serve as our reference point.  We still have $r - 1$ objects to place.  We select $r - 1$ of the $n - 1$ places, then arrange the remaining $r - 1$ objects in those places. This can be done in 
$$\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}(r - 1)! = \frac{(n - 1)!}{[(n - 1) - (r - 1)]!(r - 1)!} \cdot (r - 1)! = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(n - r)!} = P(n - 1, r - 1)$$ 
ways.

**Method 2:**  Alternatively, we choose $r$ of the $n$ places in the circle for the objects, then arrange them in 
$$\binom{n}{r}r! = \frac{n!}{(n - r)!r!} \cdot r! = \frac{n!}{(n - r)!}$$
ways.  Since placements are invariant under rotation, we must divide by the $n$ possible starting places in a given notation, which yields 
$$\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n - r)!} = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(n - r)!} = P(n - 1, r - 1)$$
distinguishable arrangements.

Notice that this formula applies when $0 \leq r \leq n$.

> In how many ways can $r$ objects be arranged consecutively in a circle when $n$ places are available?

Think about the problem this way.  If $r < n$, we have two blocks to arrange, one consisting of $n - r$ consecutive empty places and the other consisting of the $r$ consecutive places where the $r$ objects will be arranged.  The two blocks can only be arranged in one way since they must be adjacent.  Within the block of $r$ consecutive places, the objects can be arranged in $r!$ ways.  Therefore, when $r < n$, there are $r!$ ways to arrange the $r$ objects consecutively.

In counting these cases, you did not take invariance under rotation into account, so you forgot to divide your answer by $n$.

When $r = n$, we no longer have a block of empty objects.  Once we place one of the objects as our reference point, the remaining $n - 1$ objects can be arranged around the circle in $(n - 1)!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the circle.

> Does the first case include the second case?

Absolutely.

Notice that if $r < n$, then $r! \leq P(n - 1, r - 1)$ since 
\begin{align*}
P(n - 1, r - 1) & = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(n - r)!}\\
  & = \underbrace{(n - 1)(n - 2) \ldots [(n - 1) - (r - 1)]}_{r - 1~\text{terms}}\\   
  & \geq r(r - 1)(r - 2) \ldots  \cdot 2\\ 
  & = r!
\end{align*}
with equality holding if and only if $r = n - 1$.

If $r = n$, then 
$$P(n - 1, r - 1) = P(n - 1, n - 1) = (n - 1)!$$

Comment: do you mean the answer for the second case is r!  not n r! ?

Comment: Yes, when $r < n$, the number of ways of arranging $r$ consecutive objects in a circle with $n$ places is $r!$.  When $r = n$, it is $(n - 1)!$.